# SQL select if value higher save as column1, else save as column2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
IF datalength(U_Partner) > 5 THEN save value '9999' into room_id and U_Partner value into partners_id  
IF datalength(U_Partner) <= 4 THEN save value U_Partner into room_id and '9999'
value into partners_id

CASE WHEN datalength T5.U_Partner > 5 THEN '9999' ELSE T5.U_Partner END as room_id,
```

I have this, but I don't know how to add second save. Is it even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two `Case` in this scenario. each `Case` for each column. The code would be something like this:

```
Select
CASE WHEN datalength(T5.U_Partner) > 5 THEN '9999' ELSE T5.U_Partner END as room_id,
CASE WHEN datalength(T5.U_Partner) > 5 THEN T5.U_Partner ELSE '9999' END as partners_id
```

Comment: Somehow it is giving me 3 digits number (275,167) into partners_id and 9999 into room_id. U_Partner is ntext..Before could look like 275;60008;167 So I just import first value into new table T5.U_Partner which must be ntext also.

Comment: @Burco I dont Understand what r u trying to do. Do you just want to Select value? or Do you want to Insert those value into another table?

Comment: Also, its good to not use `ntext`. Better to use `nvarchar` as the msdn said. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: just select.. And I would like to use different but I am working with SAP db..and they set it to ntext

Comment: FINAL: CASE WHEN LEN(cast(T7.U_Partner as nvarchar(100)))>5 OR datalength(T7.U_Partner)=0 OR datalength(T7.U_Partner) IS NULL THEN '9999' ELSE T7.U_Partner END as room_id,

Answer (score 1):

Try (not tested)

```
DECLARE @room_id nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @partners_id AS nvarchar(max)
IF datalength(U_Partner) > 5 
BEGIN
    SELECT @room_id = '9999'
    SELECT @partners_id = UPartner
END
IF datalength(U_Partner) <= 4
BEGIN
    SELECT @partners_id = '9999'
    SELECT @room_id = UPartner

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
U_Partner = CASE WHEN datalength(U_Partner) > 5 THEN room_id ELSE 9999 END
room_id = CASE WHEN datalength(U_Partner) > 5 THEN 9999 ELSE U_Partner END
```